# Edittext move only vertically android

Tags: android

I want to know how the edit text moves only vertically on touch listener in android.

Here is my implementation. It moves vertically but not accurately with my finger movement. It is flickering and it is not positioned correctly where I leave the edit text view:

```
x=event.getX();
            y=event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    /*movabletext.setY(y);*/
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    movabletext.setY(y);

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    movabletext.setY(y);

                    break;

            }


            return true;
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I may not understand you question accurately. But if you want your edit text to only move vertically just simply set the x to a constant on every press.

maybe something like this

```
x=event.getX();
        y=event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                /*movabletext.setY(y);*/
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                movabletext.setY(y);
                movabletext.setX(CONSTANT);

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                movabletext.setY(y);
                movabletext.setX(CONSTANT);

                break;

        }


        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It is moving vertically but it is flickering. and when ever i touch the edit text it is starting from the top of the screen then it is positioned to my required place. I want a smooth touch event where edit text need to follow my finger. It is almost like snap chat text on the image

Comment: ok give me a couple hours so i can test some things and ill let you know what i come up with. Sorry i can not help more as of now.

Answer (score 0):

```
                      switch (event.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                               startClickTime = 
                               Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                                break;
                            }
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                                if (clickDuration > MAX_CLICK_DURATION) 
                                {
                                    if (currX < widthScreen && currY < 
                                    heightScreen) {
                                        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams 
                                       marginParams = new 
                                    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
                                    (view.getLayoutParams());
                                        marginParams.setMargins((int) 
                                (currX - mPrevX), (int) (currY - 
                                mPrevY), 0, 0);
                                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams 
                               layoutParams = new 
                              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);

                              view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                            }
```